# Highlight arbitrary elements in html

Tags: html, css, web

I'm developing a desktop software application which looks for errors in web pages and can highlight them in the browser. Highlighted areas are somewhat arbitrary. They could be one word in a p tag, an entire a tag or an img.

In the past I've done this by rewriting the html and adding styled span tags around the highlighted area. The downside is that quite often the highlights can be obscured. For example where in image is in a div exactly its size with no overflow, any applied border, background etc. will be obscured.

What's the best way to approach this? Are there any good examples of this being done in popular software / webapps?

Limitations: I can't use JS (files are local and browsers often block this). I can however user the latest standards. The output doesn't have to validate, as long as it works on common modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Since background colors and borders can't be used, I think you'll need to place something on top of the offending element or text.  Perhaps you can use an absolute or fixed position `<div>` element with a partially transparent background.

Of course, this could get tricky with getting the coordinates.  But you might be able to use the same thing you used to do with the span and add some dummy elements within it to trick it into thinking that 0,0 is right where your span element is.