# CSS to distinguishably highlight arbitrary element regardless of current style

Tags: css

I'm looking for a bit of CSS which will allow me to provide a distinguishing characteristic to an element on the page without fundamentally altering its style.  Specifically, each element consists of some text which has an arbitrary text color and background color.  I want to create some CSS that, no matter which element it is applied to, makes that element stand out and obvious that the CSS has been applied.

The main issue seems to be that if I try to apply a separate color (for instance, to create a border around the text) it is ineffective (or less effective) against certain background colors.  And I can't apply a fixed color to override the existing colors because it might happen to be the same as the color of an existing element, making it indistinguishable from it.  I have some flexibility in the existing styles used, but not in the range of hues present, so I can't pick a color that will work with all the other colors because such a color doesn't exist.

Something like a "saturation" filter could work; all colors could be chosen from a relatively unsaturated palette, with increased saturation for highlighted elements.  However, the [CSS filter property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) seems to be experimental and not well supported.  Are there any widely available CSS properties I could use to distinguish an arbitrary element on the page?

My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18789578/highlight-arbitrary-elements-in-html), except that the solution needs to be done entirely in CSS (adding new temporary elements isn't an acceptable solution).

Comment: why is it whenever i ask a question about CSS i get downvoted?

Comment: could somebody PLEASE explain the downvote / votes to close?  I am really puzzled and this lack of feedback is not helping me ask good questions.

Comment: You could use `opacity` and lighten the element. Supports IE8+

Comment: how do you expect someone to answer this..? it's up to you to decide how it should stand out. you've to decide that no other elements in your application will have "this" property. if you don't know what all properties an element in your application have, then you can never make an element distinguishable. always there's a chance that there might be another element with the same property. you have to make sure it won't happen. we can't do anything about it. that's why the close votes on `primary opinion based` and `too broad`... you have to narrow it down and come up with a specific problem...

Comment: @avalera Not perfect but I think that will work, thanks!

Comment: No problem. I'll update as answer.

Comment: @TJ Ah ok, thanks.  I see now if I click on close that it shows the vote counts (although they don't seem to add up to the total show).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `opacity` and lighten the element. Supports IE8+

```
div {
   background-color:#F00;
   opacity:0.5;
   filter:Alpha(opacity=50); /* IE8 and earlier */
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LWs45/2/)